# How do I add a vertical line at a specific date to a Gannt chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, gantt

I created a Gantt chart from this data, using a stacked bar chart, in Excel:

[image: data for chart]

The chart looks like this:

[image: excel Gantt chart]

I'm trying to add a vertical line on a specific date (10/7) with text somewhere near it to call out that specific date. Using data in row 6 and a scatter plot, I was able to add a marker there, but if I change the type of plot from scatter to line, there's no vertical line and no marker either.

[image: chart options]

Everything else is correct (the axes, grid lines, etc.). It's just the vertical line that needs fixing. Is it possible to do this in Excel?

I'm using Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches I can think of.

1. Draw the line manually. This is the least effort if you need to do it only once, but it doesn't automate the process of doing it repeatedly.
2. Draw the bars vertically instead of horizontally, and add empty phases before and after the phases you really need. Add a series of equal values stretching across all of the phases (including the empty ones), and format that series as a line. This will give you a horizontal line perpendicular to the bars, which is what you want, but the whole chart will be 90 degrees rotated from what you want.
3. Add additional series, as shown below. Note that the bars are in two separate series, depending on whether they're before or after the reference date, and you'll need three different series for the gaps between visible bars. You'll also need one series for the reference line. You'll need to write formulas to get the lengths of the bars and gaps to be correct. In the dialog box to Format Data Series, reduce the Gap Width to No Gap, so the segments of the perpendicular line all meet properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the topics covered in my tutorial, [Gantt Charts in Microsoft Excel](https://peltiertech.com/excel-gantt-charts/). The approach I use is to add a point at that data, with a vertical error bar. A data label can be added to the data point.